# How to bring sleeping process back to foreground?

Tags: process, docker

I used ssh to connect to a server, and run a process in docker.

`docker exec -ti docker_name /bin/bash`

However, the ssh connection broke at some point, when I went back, command `top` shows

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                      
   26 dockeru+  20   0 55.830g 0.024t 1.223g S   3.3 39.9 403:55.61 blocksci_parser
```

The status of this process is sleeping. However, the process writes data to a file, and the size of the file continues to grow, so that means the process is still running, right?

I didn't use screen or anything else to keep it running, so `jobs` returns nothing, that means I can not use `fg` to bring it back to foreground. Is there any method for me to bring this process to foreground?

Comment: There is https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-reptyr/ which tries to do what you want.

Comment: When a process reads or writes then it goes to sleeping state.

Comment: @icarus It returns:[-] Unable to open the tty in the child.
Unable to attach to pid 26: No such file or directory

Comment: Are you running reptyr inside or outside the container? Is the container privileged?

Comment: @icarus inside the contained, and the container is privileged.:(

Answer (score 1):

```
$ docker container list -qa
57f494f3190b
$ docker container attach 57f494f3190b
```

Comment: I haven't tried that because what I did seems to re-execute it:(